# Redux is changing state of component and then it turns back to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new Redux developer. I am trying to create a tab component using React and Redux in a web application.

When I select a tab I can in the console and in Redux Dev Tool that the state is changed, but as soon it changes it turns back to initial state (it happens to '' or 'tabData' or 'tabBulletin' in tabReducer.js

I don't understand it to solve this logical issue. Please, could anyone help me get wiser on this?

Thank you.

This is the parent React Tags related to the issue

```
<TabsHeader>
  <TabHeader id='tab1-tab' label='Data | 34' target='tabData' />
  <TabHeader id='tab2-tab' label='Bulletins | 35' target='tabBulletin' />
</TabsHeader>
<TabsContent>

</TabsContent>
```

TabHeader.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { selectTab } from './tabActions'

class TabHeader extends Component {
    render() {
        const selected = this.props.tab.selected === this.props.target
        return (

                <a href='/' id={this.props.id}
                onClick={() => this.props.selectTab(this.props.target)}
                data-target={this.props.target}
                className={selected ? 'active' : '' } 
            >
                {this.props.label}
            </a>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ tab: state.tab })
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ selectTab }, 
dispatch)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TabHeader)
```

tabActions.js

```
export function selectTab(tabId) {
    console.log(tabId)
    return {
        type: 'TAB_SELECTED',
        payload: tabId
    }
}
```

tabReducer.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { selected: 'tabData' }

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TAB_SELECTED':
            return { ...state, selected: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dispatched wrong way. Where did you read this ?

```
dispatch => bindActionCreators({ selectTab }, dispatch)
```

All you need is just a simple dispatch like this:

```
dispatch => ({ selectTab: tabId => selectTab(tabId) })
```

That's is.

Answer (score 0):

I am back again and now with the solution:

The problem is here on the tag of the component in TabHeader.js: 
This makes the site to be reloaded turn it to initial state

So I changed to "javaxritp:;" which solves the issue with Redux.

The line below is to map action creators that allows to be trigged to send to reducers to develop state. I may loosing a small thing that makes Redux turn it back to initial state. I learnt that from my React class. Thank you anyway.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ selectTab }, dispatch)
dispatch => bindActionCreators({ selectTab }, dispatch)
```

Comment: Mark accepted answer your solution so someone have same problem with you can see.